# Output many to many information

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can't solve the problem how to show the UserName list next to the @tweet number.Likes.Count (), help to display the list of users who tweeted (User1, User2, etc)

```
public class Like
            {
                public int Id { get; set; }
                public Guid TweetId { get; set; }
                public int UserId { get; set; }
            }

         public class Tweet
        {
            public Guid Id { get; set; }

            [MaxLength(140)]
            public string Text { get; set; }

            public int AuthorId { get; set; }
            public TwitterUser Author { get; set; }

            public List<Like> Likes { get; set; }
        }

         public class TwitterUser
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string UserName { get; set; }
            public string Bio { get; set; }

            public List<Tweet> Tweets { get; set; }
        }


    public IActionResult Index()
            {
                var tweets = _applicationDb.Tweets
                    .Include(t => t.Author)
                    .Include(t => t.Likes)
                    .Take(10);
                return View(tweets);
            }

@model IEnumerable<TestMany.Models.Tweet>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}
```

Don't know how to even resolve this problem. I will be glad for any help

Comment: <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
                <ul>
                    @foreach(var tweet in Model)
                    {
                        <li>
                            <h3>@tweet.Text</h3>
                            <div class="text-muted">@tweet.Author.UserName
                                <span>@tweet.Likes.Count()</span><span>(a list of UserName who is tweeted)</span>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the rest of the view code